# what is the best practice to do the following using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am just trying to add some functions to hover. the below does about the same thing except the one with the for loop i have the target stored in an array. I actually have a few questions.

1. is this the correct use of stopPropagation?
2. what's the best practice for doing something like this?
3. which one of the below method is faster and uses less resources?
4. I know I can use hover() but I used bind because I thought it is faster, is my thinking correct?

thank you

```
    for (var i in slides) {
        $(slides[i].el).bind( {
            mouseenter: function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                // do something
            },
            mouseleave: function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                //do something
            }
        });
    }

    $("#vehicleSlides .vehicleAreas").bind( {
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            // do something
        },
        mouseleave: function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - is this the correct use of stopPropagation

If you wish to stop the event bubbling up the DOM tree, then yes.

> 2 - what's the best practice for doing something like this

Personally, I prefer the jQuery selector followed by methods, but this is just a preference. The best practice is whatever style you and your team all agree upon and use consistently.

> 3 - which one of the below method is faster and uses less resources

In practical terms, there will be next to no difference between the two.

> 4 - I know I can use hover() but I used bind because I thought it is faster, is my thinking correct

The jQuery hover method is shorthand for the bind to mouseenter and mouseleave events, so there will be one extra function call using hover, however there will be almost no difference in performance.

Comment: I do want to stop the bubbling, what I meant was if stopping bubbling is the right thing to do. in terms of speed, isn't it better to stop the bubbling? I just want the function on that one element so isn't it better to stop the bubbling?

Comment: Perhaps, but browsers *should* be optimised for bubbling behaviour, so there may possibly be a performance gain in not stopping propagation or there may not be. You'd need to measure them all to be sure. In practical terms it is best to do what expresses your intent rather than concern yourself with micro-optimisations. In modern browsers there will be very little difference in terms of performance.

Comment: ok thanks, I am just trying to achieve the best code possible but not too sure what that is.

Comment: Optimization would involve keeping track during the capture phase of which parent nodes had attached bubble-phase event handlers for the event type.  If for example it entered the target/bubbling phase knowing that no parent nodes had handlers, it could skip the entire bubbling phase, or jump directly to nodes known to have handlers.  That's poor design however, IMO, because you might want to attach new handlers to parent nodes at any time, or you may want to move a node to another parent to try to cause the event to bubble up a different parent chain. Try it and see how it behaves.

Comment: You'd be as likely to hinder performance worrying about bubble events. The whole thing is built on a nodal system. Under the hood there are probably dozens to hundreds of events for every reflow.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would make consistently correct functionality the highest priority, so it depends on whether or not the event should be seen or heard by a parent node once processed.

That depends on your design.  For example, in a "window"-like object that you want to be able to drag around, you could either A. attach a mouse handler to the entire window, or B. attach a listener to a child "background" object to detect the mouse down event to begin dragging.

If you choose design B., then you have to make sure labels and other objects you don't want to receive mouse events have mouse events disabled (in Flash [AS3] set mouseEnabled and mouseChildren to false; not sure about JavaScript).  One con of this design is that it would prevent any object in the U.I. from passively processing or modifying event behavior in the bubbling phase, because any interception in the capture phase would prevent it from reaching the background in the first place.  One pro of this design is that by allowing the event to bubble, you could have monitors and other global effects processing mouse clicks at higher levels.

On the other hand, if you choose design A., then you don't have to worry about making child objects transparent to the mouse (an event on a label would still bubble up to the window container itself), but instead you have to make sure that event propagation on child objects like buttons is stopped once the event is handled so that they don't reach the window handler at the top of the hierarchy.  It really depends on how you want it to function, and a hybrid approach is probably best.

You can have this down to a design science to the point where the "design" isn't a design at all, but a complex truth known to be true scientifically.

Any browser optimization of this system would involve keeping track, during the capture phase, of which parent nodes had bubble-phase event handlers attached for the event type. If for example it entered the target/bubbling phase knowing that no parent nodes had handlers, it could skip the entire bubbling phase, or jump directly to nodes known to have handlers. That's poor design however, IMO, because you might want to attach new handlers to parent nodes at any time during capture or bubbling, or you may want to move a node to another parent to try to cause the event to bubble up a different parent chain. Try it and see how it behaves in different browsers.  There's bound to be huge inconsistency like anything else involving HTML rendering and event processing, in terms of both behavior and performance :P

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not much difference between bind and hover. Work avoidance is always a good thing to consider but 1-3 more function calls to get to an event handler isn't going to put a dent in a modern JIT's performance.

You are not invoking stopPropagation incorrectly but if you're doing it for no particular reason other than bubbling making you uncomfortable or because you're afraid of triggering something else by accident, then yes, you are doing it wrong.

The first rule of UI work should always be:

**DON'T DO ANYTHING YOU DON'T NEED TO DO**

Examples:

- Don't solve problems you don't have yet.
- Don't do anything "just in case," because that means you don't know what's actually happening and you really need to understand what your stuff actually does and how it works before you call anything done in UI.
- Don't stop people from using your UI differently than anticipated. e.g. validating HTML format and throwing errors when somebody tries to make something you wrote work a little differently. What are you, running a customer support line?  It helps no one/serves  nothing. What does it matter if they prefer a more semantically correct unordered list to a pile of divs?

But on stopProp specifically, if you must use it (and it can solve some problems very elegantly so never say never) try to only hit endpoint nodes with it so other things can be added to the same container without losing the benefits of bubbling. Yes, benefits I say. Don't fear bubbling. Events moving back up the ancestor line are only likely to trigger other UI events if your HTML is a complete disaster (it should be nothing but containers all the way back up to the body, right?).

Also if you can just verify that you have the right target element in the handler before taking action, do that instead of stopProp. But cripes it pisses me off when people add `return false` and `e.stopPropagation` to every single UI handler they write. Especially when they themselves pick up the event from a container that encompasses much more than the active element in question.

So don't do that. We might work in the same office some day and I can be whiny and insufferable and I'll sabotage your cheesecake.